# 403 (Forbidden) delete file image in themer folder

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, permissions

I'm having trouble with permission to delete files that are within the theme folder. All folders and files are with permission 775 and there is no error in the code , because when I use the code in a directory before the root folder wordpress works.

-The image files are deleted via front-end .

The error:

```
DELETE http://www.mysite.com.br/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme/cliente/server/php/index.php?file=imagem3.png 

403 (Forbidden)jquery.min.js:4
```

It seems that the javascript I'm using does not have permission to delete the files , but it only has to perform upload.

How can I solve this permission ? Or was it this lack of account : wp_enqueue_script

Comment: You can delete by PHP, Use ajax

Comment: This work, but before wordpress folder.

Comment: you may need to set the ownership of the folder to apache

Comment: You can del by executing linux command 
"rm " from here you can get help https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DeletingFiles

to execute in PHP use exec()